# Org mode how to apply 4 spaces for tab without initial indent inside source-code-block?

Tags: org-mode, indentation

On this example, cursor is at beginning of `if` when I press `tab` 2 space indent is added beginning of `if` block, which is aligned.

```
** TODO help            |  ** TODO help
#+begin_src python      |  #+begin_src python
if True                 |    if True             # 2 space added to beginning
  print(True)           |      print(True)       #
  if True:              |      if True:          #
    print("World")      |        print("World")  #
#+end_src               |  #+end_src
```

Would it be possible to apply `(setq org-adapt-indentation nil)` into `#+begin_src...#+end_src`  region as well where pressing `TAB` will no do initial tab alignment.

Also would it be possible to set the indent as four spaces instead of two?

---

Wanted behaviour:

```
** TODO help 
#+begin_src python 
if True          # Indent does not added            
    print(True)  # Four spcace added at the beginning   
    if True:
        print("World")
#+end_src
```

init.el:

```
(setq org-adapt-indentation nil)
(require 'org-tempo)
(defun my-tab-related-stuff ()
   (setq tab-width 4))
```

Related:

- [Inside TODO can the inner-block start without a indent in org-mode? [duplicate]](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/68112/18414)
- [Emacs org-mode python blocks have 5 space tabs, but I want 4 space tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21167633/2402577)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize the variable `org-edit-src-content-indentation` and set it to 0. The doc string of the variable says:

```
org-edit-src-content-indentation is a variable defined in ‘org-src.el’.
Its value is 2

  This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
  satisfies the predicate ‘wholenump’.
  You can customize this variable.

Documentation:
Indentation for the content of a source code block.

This should be the number of spaces added to the indentation of the #+begin
line in order to compute the indentation of the block content after
editing it with ‘M-x org-edit-src-code’.

It has no effect if ‘org-src-preserve-indentation’ is non-nil.
```

As a corollary, you should also make sure that `org-src-preserve-indentation` is `nil`.